# Credit card validation with parsleyJS

Tags: parsley.js

In version 1.x, it seems that there was credit cart validation in extras via data-luhn="true".

In version 2.0, is there similar method to check credit card validity ?

Answer (score 0):

Nope there is currently not. There is in Parsley2 repo an https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/tree/master/src/extra/validator directory where special or non usual validators could fit. v1 luhn validator should be ported here if you want to use it with Parsley2 and give it to the community too.

Best

Answer (score 0):

As of December 2014, support for luhn validation has been restored to Parsley.

Follow these steps to add Parsley's Luhn support:

- Download [luhn.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/master/src/extra/validator/luhn.js) from Parsley github
- Includ it in your code **before** including parsley.js / parsley.min.js
- Add `data-parsley-luhn="true"` to the credit card `input`

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code somewhere in your code:

```
if (typeof Parsley !== 'undefined') {
    //add the custom message:
    Parsley.addMessages('lang', {
        luhn: 'Please provide valid credit card'
    });

    //set the locale:
    Parsley.setLocale('lang');

    //add the credit card validator:
    Parsley.addValidator('luhn',
        function (value) {
            val = value.replace(/[ -]/g, '');
            var digit, n, sum, _j, _len1, _ref2;
            sum = 0;
            _ref2 = val.split('').reverse();
            for (n = _j = 0, _len1 = _ref2.length; _j < _len1; n = ++_j) {
                digit = _ref2[n];
                digit = +digit;
                if (n % 2) {
                    digit *= 2;
                    if (digit < 10) {
                        sum += digit;
                    } else {
                        sum += digit - 9;
                    }
                } else {
                    sum += digit;
                }
            }
            return sum % 10 === 0;
        }, 32);
}
```

provide the input's attribute: **data-parsley-luhn="true"**

```
<input id="creditCardNumber" value="" type="text" autocomplete="off" style="direction:rtl;" data-parsley-type="number" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-luhn="true"/>
```